# First story to feature the trope "the nice self-sufficient society that welcomed us are actually cannibals"?

Tags: history-of, trope

It is not an infrequent trope in sci-fi shows for our protagonists to be struggling in their adventure, only to stumble across a seemingly nice self-sufficient society which they are welcomed into, but for it to be revealed later the society survives by cannibalising its own members/new recruits e.g. The Rain ["Have Faith"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rain_(TV_series)#Season_1_(2018)), Nightflyers ["The Sacred Gift"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightflyers_(TV_series)#Episodes) etc (ep.4 of Vampire in the Garden is a variation).

What was the first story to feature this trope?

Comment: Possibly a variation of "To Serve Man" by Damon Knight (1950), that was later made into an episode of Twilight Zone (1959).https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Serve_Man

Comment: Maybe "The sharing of flesh" by Poul Anderson? It was in 1969 iirc

Comment: Considering that this is an obvious update of the old "scary non-European cannibals eat missionaries" stories, with outer space substituted for regions of Earth, the first example is not likely to be in a clear science fiction story. The older science fiction examples show far more resemblance to these types of stories than the two examples in the question, probably because writers started realizing the unfortunate implications of the plot.

Comment: *John Carter of Mars*, *The Name of the Snake*, and indeed, *The Sharing of Flesh* are early examples that illustrate the connection.

Comment: The Galaxy Primes by EE doc Smith (1959) had one planet with a protector species called the Blood Guard who defended the normal humans. They ate their own dead routinely

Comment: @Adamant "Name of the Snake" is a fine story by a great writer, but except for having cannibals, doesn't meet any of the requirements of the question. Singular protagonist, not "protagonists"; doing missionary work, not having an "adventure"; doesn't "stumble on" the Analoi, visits them on purpose; and they dont **survive** by cannibalising", which they onlypractice on the occasional missionary.

Comment: Now who wrote that story about a small town of cannibals in New England?

Comment: @Adamant Also in the middle of this H.G.Wells'"The Time Machine". The morlocks are certainly futuristic and, while not "a nice, self sufficient society", they are advanced enough to produce goods.

Comment: @ZabZonk There weren't any cannibals in "To Serve Man".

Comment: Does Circe count? She gives Odysseus and his crew guest rights then turns all of the crewmembers into pigs...

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FalseUtopia

Comment: This happens in _[The Integral Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Integral_Trees)_ by Larry Niven,  or possibly its sequel _The Smoke Ring_. But I doubt it's the first. I wonder if 
 _Soylent Green_ counts....

Answer (score 8):

In Poul Anderson's *Welcome* (F&SF  Oct 1960), a time  traveller into the future finds himself in a highly non-egalitarian society. At the end he is invited to dine and the sit down to "roast suckling coolie".

Answer (score 6):

I asked a different question based on this and I got the answer **Disqualified** by Charles Fontenay from 1954

A colony world has an underclass of workers who are also used as meat.

[Planet of cannibals](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263376/planet-of-cannibals)