# Planet of cannibals

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This question [First story to feature the trope "the nice self-sufficient society that welcomed us are actually cannibals"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/245815/first-story-to-feature-the-trope-the-nice-self-sufficient-society-that-welcomed)
jogged my memory about a sci-fi short story that I read maybe fifteen years ago.

Two diplomats visit a planet to meet the high officials, a long lost earth colony; they are served a big steak dinner and all is 'laughy clappy' and good fun.

They are strolling back to their ship through fields, etc., and the junior remarks on the large number of farm labourers toiling in the distance. Are they the underclass mentioned at the meeting?

The older one comments on the planet's lack of any animals to function as horsepower, etc. He casually urges his co-worker to hasten until they're in the ship and blasted off.

The junior asks the problem, and the senior reminds him of the thick tender steak they'd eaten on a world with zero livestock

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two men are guests on a planet terraformed some generations ago. All earth livestock died. Local animals cannot be eaten. Served meat in a meal](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/286550/two-men-are-guests-on-a-planet-terraformed-some-generations-ago-all-earth-lives)

(This is the older question of the two, but the other has the full text in the answer, which is probably better)

Comment: @AndresF. why close in that direction? This QA has more votes, views and is older

Comment: @fez I think I explained in my comment?

Comment: @AndresF. Seems like the dupe target is a poorer technical “answer” imo

Comment: @fez I disagree, I prefer the other one because I get to read the full story. Feel free to vote to reopen this one and close the other. Or take it to meta, I suppose.

Comment: @AndresF. As the answerer to this question I clearly have a vested interest ;)  but I have to say I disagree with you. I prefer to see a brief summary of the story, and have an option to read the full text. That's more economical, and also avoids copyright problems (admittedly not a problem in this case, but could happen with other answers if someone quotes the whole text).

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez I actually agree with you in cases with longer text, but in this case the story is so short it barely takes longer than the explanation! And it saves me trouble to go looking for a story that piqued my interest. I'm a reader first, I don't care for fake internet points. But I'm open to the community voting otherwise :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This sounds very much like *[Disqualified](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46227)*, a short story by Charles Fontenay, first published in *If* in 1954.

The story concerns two inspectors visiting a colonised world, who have to decide whether to give them technical assistance. As in the question, the world lacks any draught animals or livestock, and so all work is done by human power. The less experienced inspector, Peo, was concerned about whether there was slavery:

> Tardo had seemed most intent on the question of slavery, and Peo
> looked for signs of it. He could see none. The people of the planet
> had had time to conceal some things, of course. But the people they
> saw in the village wore a proud air of independence no slave could
> assume.

The more experienced man realised that the planet hid a dark secret, and that beside the happy "freemen" they saw, there must be other humans, little better than animals:

> If you remember your history, colonizing ships 1000 years ago had no
> space to carry animals along. They had to depend on native animal life
> of the planet, and this planet had none."
>
> "Saranta said that. But I don't see ..."
>
> "Those were delicious steaks, weren't they?" remarked Tardo quietly.

The full story is available at [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/30251/30251-h/30251-h.htm).

Comment: Pretty cool short story. I wish there was a series of short stories about inspectors Tardo & Peo.